# Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null in npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I searched this issue everywhere. But still couldn't find an answer. Most of answers say there's a problem with proxy. When I try to use `npm install -g package-name` an error is occurred.

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-27T14_55_06_994Z-debug.log
```

Here is the .log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose npm-session bd0a5d284789daec
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
8 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
8 verbose stack     at getProxy (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\agent.js:164:25)
8 verbose stack     at getAgent (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\agent.js:37:19)
8 verbose stack     at remoteFetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:310:17)
8 verbose stack     at opts.cacheManager.match.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:172:14)
8 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:432:57)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:524:17)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
9 verbose cwd C:\
10 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
11 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
12 verbose node v8.10.0
13 verbose npm  v5.6.0
14 error Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Versions
node - 8.10.0
npm - 5.6.0

Comment: what is output you see when you execute this command `npm get registry`

Comment: My output - https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided in [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15348) post

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work for me. And also I'm runnig these commands on windows.

Answer (score 10):

Finally after two days of hard working I found the answer.
There was no proxy set in my configs in npm. Thats why when I tried `npm config get proxy` it was null. But there were two environmental variables set in my pc call http-proxy and https-proxy. But I don't know how they were set there. So I deleted those variables. Now my npm install works fine.

Comment: Wow.. This helped me. Thank you.

Comment: can you gave me the path of .npmrc file

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem cause I manually remove the `https-proxy` and `proxy` settings in the `.npmrc` file. after I add it back everything get worked.

Comment: can you gave me the path of .npmrc file

Comment: on windows: %USERPROFILE%\.npmrc

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue while building the Angular 6 image with Docker (v18.09.0).

The Proxy variables of node and Docker environment were causing the problem. The solution is to reset `httpProxy` variable value as told here: [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client). Also, set project specific `.npmrc` like: [gist](https://gist.github.com/nikhilbchilwant/7243ea4c6f35f28fb44376dac675d285) and fix the `npm` permission issue: [gist](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/tools/ngcontainer/Dockerfile#L51)

Finally, my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM node:10.14.2-alpine
###
#Issue: 'Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null in npm install' error
#Reason: Proxy variables of node and Docker environment were causing the problem.
#Solution: Modify httpProxy variable value as told here: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client
# Also, set project specific .npmrc like : https://gist.github.com/nikhilbchilwant/7243ea4c6f35f28fb44376dac675d285

#RUN apk add tree

WORKDIR /home/node/aas-ui

#Fix for npm permission issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/tools/ngcontainer/Dockerfile#L51
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global \
 && npm config set prefix '/home/node/.npm-global' \
 && echo "export PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH" >> /home/node/.profile
RUN source /home/node/.profile

RUN chown -R node $(npm config get prefix)
RUN chown -R node /home/node/aas-ui
USER node

COPY src ./src/
COPY e2e ./e2e/
COPY .angular-cli.json ./angular-cli.json
COPY protractor.conf.js ./protractor.conf.js
COPY karma.conf.js ./karma.conf.js
COPY tslint.json ./tslint.json
COPY package.json .
COPY angular.json .
COPY .npmrc .
RUN npm install --verbose
RUN npm build --verbose
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org

Answer (score 0):

I had to set my http and https proxy so that npm can fetch packages

`npm config set proxy http://[IP]:[port]`

`npm config set https_proxy http://[IP]:[port]`

Then `npm i` installed all packages for me.

cheers!